# Javascript For Loop execution on dom element

Tags: javascript

I have javascript code to get the elements with class name and iterate over that remove the class from elements.

```
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
       console.log("Length " + elements.length)
        for (var i=0; i< elements.length;i++) {
               console.log("---- "+i)
               elements[i].setAttribute("class","");
         }
```

and there are 3 span with the class name "test". HTML code is

```
<span class="test" id="test1">Test1 </span>
<span class="test" id="test2">Test2 </span>
<span class="test" id="test3">Test3 </span>
```

But I am getting only 2 class removed. The second span class still remains there.

The console output is

> Length 3
>
> ---- 0
>
> ---- 1

Comment: i < elements.length in this case i < 2 will only give you 0,1 you'll need to use <= (lower and equal) to get 3 values ;)

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a *live list*. Changing the class will remove the elements from the list. You need to make a copy of them somehow before removing them

Comment: @Hammster Except that there are 3 elements...

Comment: @RGraham: Or, more efficiently, process them back to front. This way, you are already finished with the part of the collection that gets disturbed.

Comment: @Juhana NodeLists, like arrays, have 0 based indices...

Comment: @danwellman `elements.length` is 3 no matter what based indices you use.

Comment: @Amadan Yup, also an option.

Comment: @Juhana you don't use the length to get the elements, you use the index. In a NodeList of 3 elements, elements[3] === undefined

Comment: @danwellman Look, Hammster said "i < elements.length in this case i < 2" which is wrong because `elements.length` is 3, not 2. We're talking about the list length here. No-one has said anything about `elements[3]`.

Comment: @juhana is right i messed up ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[getElementsByClassName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) object, which gets updated when you remove the class from the elements.

So one simple logic you can use is to use a while loop and see if the collection has any items, if so remove the class from the first item.

```js
function removeClass() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
  console.log("Length " + elements.length)
  while (elements.length) {
    elements[0].setAttribute("class", "");
  }
}
```

```css
.test {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="test" id="test1">Test1 </span>
<span class="test" id="test2">Test2 </span>
<span class="test" id="test3">Test3 </span>
<button onclick="removeClass()">Test</button>
```