# Iterating over DOM element

Tags: javascript

I am iterating DOM elements using a for loop, using 2 syntax and in both I am getting different results.

The JavaScript method 1 is

```
for (var sortable in document.getElementsByClassName('test')) {
           console.log("---- " + sortable)
           sortable.setAttribute('class', '');
    }
```

Th output for this gives error

> undefined is not a function

for `sortable.setAttribute('class', '');` line.

And using javascript 2 method

```
   var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");

   for (var i=0; i< elements.length;i++) {
         elements[i].setAttribute("class", "");
   }
```

I get the appropriate result.

My html code is

```
       <span class="test" id="test1">Test1 </span>
        <span class="test" id="test2">Test2 </span>
        <span class="test" id="test3">Test3 </span>
```

I don't know why I don't get DOM elements in `var sortable in document.getElementsByClassName('test')` as `sortable`?

Comment: If you just have a look at the logged value you will see that `sortable` is an numerical value then how can it have the `setAttribute` method ?

Comment: for in is not the same as a regular for loop

Comment: But I am itering on `getElements` so sortable should be html element, how can it be number?

Comment: Because a for in loop iterates over the object properties. It's not the same as a foreach or for-loop..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do a `for .. in` loop in JavaScript, it is important to know that the value returned by the for loop is actually the key and not the value.

So you could try this:

```
var testElements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');

for (var key in testElements) {
    var sortable = testElements[key];
    console.log("---- " + sortable)
    sortable.setAttribute('class', '');
}
```

However, this would fail as there are many properties defined on the value returned by `getElementsByClassName`, which not all return an element.

You can see them all by doing the following:

```
for (var key in document.getElementsByClassName('test')) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

This will output something like this:

```
0
1
2
test1
test2
test3
length
item
namedItem
```

You can see that not only does the returned value contain the numerical indexes, it also has the ID's as properties and also an `item` and `namedItem` property.

Unfortunatety, your for-loop also doesn't work as you are changing the class name and `getElementsByClassName` returns a "live" collection, which means that once you change the class, it is removed from the collection.

You can work around this with a simple loop:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");

while (elements.length > 0) {
    elements[0].setAttribute("class", "");
}
```

This solution was taken from: [Javascript For Loop execution on dom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198445/javascript-for-loop-execution-on-dom-element)

Comment: Your last `for` loop will not work... see the same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198445/javascript-for-loop-execution-on-dom-element

Comment: @ArunPJohny Correct, I have fixed the answer. I will also link to that question.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByClassName returns an array of all the elements.

For-in only iterates over objects, not arrays.

Comment: Arrays are a type of object in JavaScript.